# JSON.NET encoding

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json.net

I have a bbcode parser which parse bbcode on the server side into html string and then present the result as html to end users using JQuery on the client side.

When i return the object using JSON.NET's .SerailizeObject, by default, it encodes all html.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyBBCodeObject, Formatting.None)
```

My original already 'Parsed" html string is

```
<blockquote><p>test</p></blockquote>
```

and JSON.NET's serializer returns

```
&lt;blockquote&gt;&lt;p&gt;Test&lt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;
```

My question is, how do I prevent JSON.NET from html encoding my already "Parsed" (a property MyBBCodeObject) string?

The result is, I have to use JQuery template's {{html}} to decode them when presented to the user, and that caused an additional 4 seconds load time.

Any advice is greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Are you **sure** json.net is html-encoding it? are you sure that isn't actually your web code when writing it to the response? For example, if you just do `string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyBBCodeObject, Formatting.None)`, what is `s` ? (without writing `s` to the response stream!)

Comment: @Marc. You are right! Hm, it's not a JSON.NET issue. I'm returning the result from a .asmx web service and looks like it's the web service that is html encoding my responses. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how to close this thread, so I'll just answer my own question.

Thanks again to @Marc. It's the .asmx web service that is encoding my response. I'll just use httphandler for this purpose.

Comment: Just accept your own answer, and question will not appear as 'unanswered'